# How to save updated layout as png file

Tags: java, android

I use the following code to save the content of the layout in a png file. But when the content of the layout changes, I call this function again and save it in a new file. I see that it has saved the previous content.

```
picLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
picLayout.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bmCA = picLayout.getDrawingCache();

File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),folder_1_n);
if (!file.exists()){
    file.mkdirs();}

    if (file.exists()){
        FileOutputStream uotputstreem_c;

        File out_c_file= new File(file,c_filename);
        try{
            uotputstreem_c = new FileOutputStream(out_c_file);
            bmCA.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,uotputstreem_c);
            uotputstreem_c.flush();
            uotputstreem_c.close();
            if(!folder)Toast.makeText(this, "successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }}else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```